# Were laws broken, can I use in civil or small claims?

Tags: criminal-law, california, civil-law, finance, theft

Long story short my girlfriend of 5 years how to debit card to my savings account and every payday I would deposit $500 into the savings account for her to use and this went on for approximately the last two years.

5 months prior to the end of the relationship we got in a fight and those final five months I would consider us in a on-again-off-again status however she made it clear several times if I stop financially helping her the relationship would for sure be over and so because I did not want that I continued making deposits which she withdrew and to which I had made it explicitly clear I would only continue to do if we were together and working on repairing our relationship.

Come to find out she had been cheating which made me very upset as it would anyone however did me exceptionally not only because of the money but because during the same time span I had also spent roughly $1,000 repairing a car that I purchased her a couple years before.

The final straw was a restraining order was filed for but denied because I never threatened her nor ever harmed her however within the paperwork filed which I believe would then be under oath she cited one of the reasons for filing was because we had broken up at that point 5 months prior which as stated above I can clearly assure you was not the case however it is now what I would consider legally documented so my question is this...

Can she legally be held accountable either criminally or civilly if I can prove which I can that she was put on notice that that money was only continuing to be deposited on the pretenses that we were still together?

Comment: "Give me money or our relationship is over", the deposits should have stopped right there.

Answer (score 1):

No. No laws were broken.

You have no basis for a civil action of any kind against her.

You made gifts which were accepted. You cannot take those gifts back based upon something you later learned about the relationship that existed when those gifts were made by you. A complaint to that effect would be dismissed if she requested that it be on its face without even having to consider any evidence.

Likewise, none of the facts you set forth constitute a crime of any kind.

Comment: Arguably, claiming in the restraining order action that they were still together would be a crime. If it was done under other, it would be perjury.

Comment: Court pleadings are absolutely privileged from civil remedies, and when a relationship ends is to a significant extent a matter of opinion and would never be prosecuted as perjury.